# Regex PHP for spliting options of multiple choices

Tags: php, regex

I have some options in a string like -

```
string = " a) Red
                 b)Green (other information)
                 c) Black
                  d) Blue " .....
```

Options may be more than 4. 
I want  individual options as an array. Should I use regex match?  Or by finding ")" indexOf(")") then spliting it.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out something like www.regex101.com instead of having other people write your code for you.

Also, the solution your are trying to implement seems to be a very sketchy one, and I would try to see if there is any other way to format the data you are trying to use as an array first.

That being said, you can implement the following solution to obtain what you need:

```
preg_match_all('/^([a-z])\)(.*)/mi', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach( $matches AS $option ){
     echo "<option value=\"{$option[1]}\">{option[2]}</option>";
}
```

This regex will find any matches of a pattern starting with a letter, followed by ) and then with any subsequent string after that, until the next match, and put them in an array, where the zero based index is the entire string, 1 is the letter before ) and 2 is the subsequent string.